# transfer files from old pc(without os) to new one using LAN

Tags: lan, file-transfer

PC A: old one whose files is required; it doesn't have any os but I can boot it using live versions of linux(ubuntu for example) or windows repair disks;

PC B: new one; running windows 7;

two pcs are connected to each other with LAN;

How can I transfer my files from old pc to new one using lan?(I don't want to install any os on the old pc)

**I don't want to repair the old pc; it's just a case of transferring files using lan and live boot tools;**

Is there any liveboot software capable of sharing files between the two pcs?
or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If both are on LAN, and you can boot PC A using Live CD, and can access the LAN, and can access the files in PC A:

Simply create a "share folder" on your PC B running windows 7 with full read/write access by everyone/guest and then from the Live CD on PC A - connect to that shared folder, and copy everything across.

If you have a USB HDD - even easier :)

Comment: the questions is: what live cd? which live os can do this?(detecting the nic, setting the ips, share...)

Comment: I've used Ubuntu Live CD and they have been generally very good in detecting the hardware and running all the needed drivers. But this is purely personal. Setting the IP should be done automatically via DHCP (assuming that your home LAN has a router and is giving out IP address via DHCP). About accessing share folder via Ubuntu - I can't think of how on top of my head at the moment but there will be lots of instructions on how to do this. If you are familiar with other Linux Live CD, they should work as well.